# Cannot Authorize App Engine with Drive API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get a list of Drive files on my App Engine. The app is not for consumers other than the app so I'm not implementing OAuth2 for user sign in.

I have enabled Drive in the GCP project and the compute instance is an owner. However, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    credentials = app_engine.Credentials(scopes=SCOPES)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/app_engine.py",     line 105, in __init__
    'The App Engine APIs are not available.')
EnvironmentError: The App Engine APIs are not available.
```

Here is my code (based off this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts):

```
from google.auth import app_engine
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = app_engine.Credentials(scopes=SCOPES)

project_id = 'project-id'

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3',credentials=credentials)
bucket = service.files().list(project=project_id).execute()
print bucket
```

Something is going on with my credentials and I'm unsure what it is.

Tldr; How do I authorize my App Engine Flask App (Standard) to consume Google APIs, including Google Sheets, Drive, BigQuery and others. Keep in mind, this is a server-to-server job. No users are logging in other than the app itself.

Ultimately, I'm trying to have values in Google Sheets synced with BigQuery (the app needs Drive and BQ permissions) that will then get pushed to DataStore.

If you have suggestions on how to fix it, ELI5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the tutorial that you are following there is a [note](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts#authorizingrequests) that says if you need to test you application locally you should use [other credential mechanism](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts#jwtsample). In this case you have to obtain and provide the service account credentials manually. 
You need to get a JSON file with the service account key and then on your code use the service account credentials by specifying the private key file.
There is another good [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#top_of_page) that maybe can be useful for setting up authentication for server to server production applications.

Comment: Thanks! I used this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server combined with https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts to get the desired outcome